# Splitting a string on whitespaces

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm currently trying to splice a string into a multi-line string.
The regex should select white-spaces which has 13 characters before.

The problem is that the 13 character count does not reset after the previous selected white-space. So, after the first 13 characters, the regex selects every white-space.

I'm using the following regex with a `positive look-behind` of 13 characters:

```
(?<=.{13})
```

(there is a whitespace at the end)

You can test the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/kZ1bN1/2) and the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String str = "This is a test. The app should break this string in substring on whitespaces after 13 characters";

        for (String string : str.split("(?<=.{13}) ")) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
     }
}
```

The output of this code is as follows:

> This is a test.
>   The
>   app
>   should
>   break
>   this
>   string
>   in
>   substring
>   on
>   whitespaces
>   after
>   13
>   characters

But it should be:

> This is a test.
>   The app should
>   break this string
>   in substring on
>   whitespaces after
>   13 characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may actually use a lazy limiting quantifier to *match* the lines and then replace with `$0\n`:

```
.{13,}?[ ]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eV5cA1/1)

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/1mIFLE):

```
String str = "This is a test. The app should break this string in substring on whitespaces after 13 characters"; 
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(".{13,}?[ ]", "$0\n"));
```

Note that the pattern matches:

- `.{13,}?` - any character that is not a newline (if you need to match any character, use DOTALL modifier, though I doubt you need it in the current scenario), 13 times at least, and it can match more characters but up to the first space encountered
- `[ ]` - a literal space (a character class  is redundant, but it  helps visualize the pattern).

The replacement pattern - `"$0\n"` - is re-inserting the whole matched value (it is stored in Group 0) and appends a newline after it.

Comment: Oh thanks. I didn't think of matching the strings and use matching groups like this. I always struggle with matching groups when I want to select them. I deleted my previous comment because I read your answer too quickly.

Comment: Ok, I think you did not expect that the whole match value can be backreferenced with `$0` in the replacement pattern.

Comment: Exactly. I usually use regex only for matching mail addresses, numbers, etc... (and not with Java).

Comment: and by the way, do I really need to use the brackets around the whitespace ?

Comment: As I mentioned, no, you do not have to. In Java, it does not make much sense as even with the COMMENTS (`(?x)`) mode selected, spaces inside character classes are ignored. I added them to just make the space stand out.

Answer (score 3):

You can just match and capture 13 characters before white spaces rather than splitting.

Java code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(.{13}) +" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( text );

List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group(1));
}
```

It will produce:

```
This is a test.
The app should
break this string
in substring on
whitespaces after
13 characters
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZ1bN1/4)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but Wiktor's answer is shorter and doesn't need Pattern or Matcher objects. +1 for you anyway for showing me the `Matcher.group()` method.

Comment: Return value of `split` is a String array not a string with `\n`. In order to get an array this much additional code is needed. What if your original string already has `\n` in it then how would you figure out where is the original `\n` and where is the newly inserted one

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the .split and using regular expression. It would be like this

```
line.split("\\s+");
```

This will spilt every word with one or more whitespace.

Comment: I think you need to re-read the question. (And I already got an answer)